# Unable to download iOS Enterprise App from password protected server

Tags: ios, enterprise

We are trying to set up a private server for our Enterprise Apps but I am constantly getting the message 'Unable to Download App'.

We have configured our apps, profiles, plist files etc correctly as the download works when we remove password protection the server.

However, as soon as we add password protection to the server, the download fails. I think this is because the authenticated session is only valid within Safari, yet the app download is a background task taking place outside of Safari and therefore unauthenticated.

Is there a way to persist the session beyond Safari in a background task?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is a snippet of the log.....

Latest log....

```html
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mediaserverd(CoreAudio)[30] <Notice>: HALS_IOContext.cpp:855:StopIOProcID:  HALS_IOContext::StopIOProcID: 163 Actuator (VAD [vzzz] AggDev 4):
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mediaserverd(CoreAudio)[30] <Notice>: HALS_IOContext.cpp:861:StopIOProcID:  HALS_IOContext::StopIOProcID: stopping 0x0 state: Prewarm: 1 Play: 0 State: Prewarmed IOProc 0x21: no
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 lsd(MobileCoreServices)[17777] <Notice>: <private>application launch failed - received error <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 lsd(MobileCoreServices)[17777] <Notice>: [Start] not launching application - result = Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.AppStore" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process did not launch, but SpringBoard provided no explanation., BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse, NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.AppStore" failed.}
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: Result code socket 17 created 00000000 00000019
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, staging.uk.mydomain.com., Addr) START PID[115](itunesstored)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: InitDNSConfig: Setting StopTime on question 00000001080114B8 staging.uk.mydomain.com. (Addr)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: GetServerForQuestion: 00000001080114B8 DNS server (0000000107D2E2B0) 10.16.160.1:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0000000000000000:-1) found for name staging.uk.mydomain.com. (Addr)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: InitDNSConfig: question 00000001080114B8 staging.uk.mydomain.com. (Addr) Timeout 30, DNS Server 10.16.160.1:53
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: ShouldSuppressUnicastQuery: Query not suppressed for staging.uk.mydomain.com., qtype Addr, DNSServer . 10.16.160.1:53 allows A queries
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: Result code socket 17 closed  00000000 00000019 (0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: Result code socket 17 created 00000000 0000001A
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, staging.uk.mydomain.com., AAAA) START PID[115](itunesstored)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: InitDNSConfig: Setting StopTime on question 00000001080560B8 staging.uk.mydomain.com. (AAAA)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: GetServerForQuestion: 00000001080560B8 DNS server (0000000107D2E2B0) 10.16.160.1:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0000000000000000:-1) found for name staging.uk.mydomain.com. (AAAA)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: InitDNSConfig: question 00000001080560B8 staging.uk.mydomain.com. (AAAA) Timeout 30, DNS Server 10.16.160.1:53
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: ShouldSuppressUnicastQuery: Query suppressed for staging.uk.mydomain.com., qtype AAAA, since DNS Configuration does not allow (req_A is true and req_AAAA is false)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: Result code socket 17 closed  00000000 0000001A (0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: DNSServiceQueryRecord(staging.uk.mydomain.com., Addr) ADD    4 staging.uk.mydomain.com. Addr 193.32.47.40
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: GenerateNegativeResponse: Generating negative response for question staging.uk.mydomain.com. (AAAA)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>: queryrecord_result_callback: Suppressed question staging.uk.mydomain.com. (AAAA)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: DNSServiceQueryRecord(staging.uk.mydomain.com., AAAA) ADD    0 staging.uk.mydomain.com. AAAA
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: Cancel 00000000 00000019
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 CommCenter[84] <Notice>: #I Device not camped on GSM.
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: DNSServiceQueryRecord(staging.uk.mydomain.com., Addr) STOP PID[115](itunesstored)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: Cancel 00000000 0000001A
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 mDNSResponder[105] <Info>:  14: DNSServiceQueryRecord(staging.uk.mydomain.com., AAAA) STOP PID[115](itunesstored)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 CommCenter(libCommCenterKCommandDrivers.dylib)[84] <Notice>: #I Adding inputs for LTE
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 itunesstored[115] <Notice>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: Presenting a CFUserNotification on behalf of: itunesstored.115
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: Received request to activate alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x106633030; title: Cannot connect to staging.uk.mydomain.com; source: itunesstored; pid: 115>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: Activation - Presenting <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x106633030; title: Cannot connect to staging.uk.mydomain.com; source: itunesstored; pid: 115> with presenter: <SBUnlockedAlertItemPresenter: 0x174208060>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: Undimming for source: notification
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: returning -1 from _nextLockTimeDuration because SBAutoLockTime is less than 0
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: returning -1 from _nextIdleTimeDuration because SBAutoDimTime is less than 0
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: Disabling idle timer because the next idle duration < 0.
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard[16152] <Notice>: Setting _lastBKUserEventTimerMode=0 with duration=-1.000000
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 SpringBoard(BackBoardServices)[16152] <Info>: Resetting user event timer to Disabled duration -1
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 backboardd[16153] <Info>: client com.apple.springboard - (16152) updated deferrals to {(    <BKSEventFocusDeferral: 0x10bb6aed0; <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x110f31340; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0x80b55adf> --> <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x110fa24e0; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0x50ec0f90>; Priority: 10,
<BKSEventFocusDeferral: 0x109eb80f0; <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x10bba23d0; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0xafe42cbe> --> <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x10bbbbe60; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0x50ec0f90>; Priority: 10,
<BKSEventFocusDeferral: 0x110f81e60; <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x10bbc0480; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0x49c6400c> --> <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x10bb7be60; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0x50ec0f90>; Priority: 10,
<BKSEventFocusDeferral: 0x10bba7860; <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x110f46c30; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null), 0x0> --> <BKSEventFocusDeferralProperties: 0x109eb9c20; <com.apple.springboard - 16152, (null),
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 MobileSafari(UIKit)[18211] <Notice>: app will resign active
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 MobileSafari(CloudKit)[18211] <Info>: Starting operation <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 MobileSafari(CloudKit)[18211] <Info>: Invoking main for operation <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 MobileSafari(CloudKit)[18211] <Info>: Operation <private> enqueuing on container throttle queue
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 MobileSafari(CloudKit)[18211] <Info>: Operation <private> invoking on container throttle queue
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Initialized with context 0x125da9d00. Background: 0, cellular: 1, QOS: 0x19
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Starting operation
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Starting <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 1 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 2
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 2 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 3
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 3 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 4
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 4 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 5
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 5 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 6
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 6 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 8
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation transitioning from state 8 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x127224a10] Operation is now in state 7
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x125d18ae0] Initialized with context 0x125da9d00. Background: 0, cellular: 1, QOS: 0x19
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Adding child operation <private> to parent operation <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x125d18ae0] Starting operation
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Starting <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x125d18ae0] Operation transitioning from state 1 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x125d18ae0] Operation transitioning from state 2 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x125d18ae0] Operation is now in state 2
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x125d18ae0] Operation transitioning from state 2 (cancelled=0, stop=1, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Got an error while fetching PCS data for record <private>: <private>. Fetching the zone PCS and creating new PCS data
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x1273bbf20] Initialized with context 0x125da9d00. Background: 0, cellular: 1, QOS: 0x19
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Adding child operation <private> to parent operation <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x1273bbf20] Starting operation
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Starting <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Finished operation <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x1273bbf20] Operation transitioning from state 1 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x1273bbf20] Operation is now in state 2
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x1273bbf20] Operation transitioning from state 2 (cancelled=0, stop=0, error=0)
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Notice>: [Operation 0x1273bbf20] Operation is now in state 3
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 cloudd(CloudKitDaemon)[17060] <Info>: Enqueing fetch of zone <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 routined(libcoreroutine.dylib)[3411] <Debug>: caching CMMotionActivity, <private>, RTMotionActivity, <private>
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: entry
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: txBufferLength=7 rxBufferLength=23
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: Wrote:     7B | 0x80 0x10 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>:  Read:    23B | 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x20 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11 0x01 0x21 0x00 0x04 0x0d 0x04 0x17 0x00
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: Status={0x80, 0x20, 00, 0x10, 00, 00, 00, 0x11, 0x1, 0x21, 00, 0x4, 0xd, 0x4, 0x17, 00}
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: exit, err=0x0
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: mask=0x3F, bad=false
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: exit
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: entry
Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: exit
```

Comment: Have you checked the device logs for error on this? Does your download start and then in the middle shows this error? Do you get a permission popup on ipad that trying to download

Comment: Yes. The plist downloads and begins the install process but then it halts. Added log in main post

Comment: It says No artwork available for software download: 419800105851887447.
Did you add your icon files on the server as well and mention the path in your plist?

Comment: The artwork is inside the ipa file. To clarify - this download process works fine without any password protection on the resources. As soon as we add any security to restrict access to these files, the download fails. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the elements of plist. If your plist download and app download starts, there i no problem of the server so it doesn't matter if its password protected or not. it has to do with your plist and how download is configured on server. Ideally password protected is necessary for OTA distribution.

Comment: Apologies - further clarification. Initially the plist wouldn't even download so we just unprotected the plist file whilst the ipa remained protected. Now we get the prompt to download the app (as the plist is unprotected) but the app refused to download (as the ipa remains protected)

Comment: Have both plist and ipa in the same location and in same state. both protected ideally. Also if your plist file contains the tags that mention the path of 57x57 icon and 512x52 icon then add those icons at that path as well, ideally the same path as your plist and ipa. Also ensure that the download button on web page has itms download mentioned clearly and points to plist.

Comment: @ user1654248 did it work?

Comment: Have done all them. We've added protection to all resources (as recommended and as you stated in your first post) but the download ink can't even access the plist file now (although it is accessible via a web browser). This blog post - http://ivansk.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/apples-architecture-failure-lost-cookie.html - explains exactly the same issue I am experiencing

Comment: What is now coming in your device logs.

Comment: Also is it possible for you to share the link of that app for debug purpose. If not its totally fine, then we will have to try debugging with logs :)
Because I have the same setup for quite a few of my apps and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry - can't share link as it is behind our corporate network, but I've updated the logs above with the latest. Pertinent line looks like this....Jul 18 15:35:13 Jims-iPhone-7 itunesstored[115] <Notice>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Comment: This link also answers the question. It appears iTunes needs to be able to access the plist & ipa file without a login getting in the way --> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50342